# trouble installing mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, terminal

Trying to follow [this](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ruby-on-rails/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion/) tutorial, but my installation of mysql is failing.

After getting to the last line(`launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist`), I get the following error:

```
launchctl:
 CFURLWriteDataAndPropertiesToResource
  (/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist) failed: -10
```

It is worth noting that I originally had an error for the second to last line:

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/com.mysql.mysqld.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

but I noticed I did not have a `/5.5.15/` folder, instead I had a `/5.5.14/`, which I used instead.

Also, I am only following the mySql part of the tutorial, the rest I had already done.

Incase it is relevant, I have used MAMP on this machine, but have shut it down and restarted to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error seems to indicate a permissions problem. Your homebrew installation might be a bit messed up. I'd try uninstalling mysql via homebrew via "brew uninstall mysql" and then removing homebrew entirely and reinstalling. You could also try running [this script](https://gist.github.com/768518) to fix the permissions. If that doesn't work, I'd uninstall and reinstall.